# Calculating electric field produced by spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

I'm having trouble solving this problem.

> Find the electric field a distance $z$ from the center of a spherical surface of radius $R$ that carries a uniform charge density $\sigma$. In here, $R>z$. Use coulomb's law

Let $\vec{r^{'}}$ be the position vecter for the source charges and  $\vec{r}$ be the position vector for the point we are interesting where is z away from the center of a spherical.

Then the electric field at $\vec{r}$ is $\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r^{'}}}{\vert \vec{r}-\vec{r^{'}}\vert^{3}}\sigma dA^{'} \tag{1}$

Now consider the center of spherical shell as origin and the direction from origin to origin as parallel to $\hat{z}$.

Therefore $\vec{r}=z\hat{z}$ and  $\vec{r^{'}}=R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)$

So,  $\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)}{\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert^{3}}R^{2}sin\theta \sigma d\phi d\theta \tag{2}$

And it can be expressed as:
$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{z\hat{z}}{\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert^{3}}R^{2}sin\theta\sigma d\phi d\theta- \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)}{\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert^{3}}R^{2}sin\theta\sigma d\phi d\theta \tag{3}$

What i'm confusing is from here.

I think the second term is zero because spherical chell is symmetry. So, I tried to find electric field by calculating only

$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{z\hat{z}}{\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert^{3}}R^{2}sin\theta\sigma d\phi d\theta \tag{4}$

By law of cosine, $\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert=(R^2+z^2-Rzcos\theta)^{1/2}$.

$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{z\hat{z}}{\vert z\hat{z}-R\hat{r}(\phi,\theta)\vert^{3}}R^{2}sin\theta\sigma d\phi d\theta=\frac{z\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{R^{2}sin\theta\hat{z}}{(R^2+z^2-Rzcos\theta)^{3/2}} d\phi d\theta=\frac{z\sigma R^{2}}{2\epsilon_0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{sin\theta\hat{z}}{(R^2+z^2-Rzcos\theta)^{3/2}} d\theta=\frac{z\sigma R^{2}}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{z}[-\frac{1}{Rz}(R^{2}+z^{2}-2Rzcos\theta)^{-1/2}]^{\pi}_{0}=\frac{z\sigma R^{2}}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{z}(\frac{1}{Rz}(\frac{1}{z+R}-\frac{1}{z-R})) \tag{5}$

As a result it was wrong.I have the solution for this problem. But i want to know why this was wrong way.

Comment: Is $Z$ different from $z$?

Comment: @Ghoster, Sorry they are same. I'll fix it right now

Comment: I suggest numbering your equations with `\tag{n)`.

Comment: *I think the second term is zero.* Since you’re not getting the right answer, maybe you should check this assumption by calculating this term.

Comment: Why are you integrating when you could use Gauss’ Law?

Comment: @Ghoster I tried to solve the problem as required. The problem require to use coulomb's law

Comment: If you have to integrate, it would be easier to integrate to compute the potential, and then take its gradient to get the field.

Comment: *The problem require to use coulomb's law.* Then you should state that in the post.

Comment: *I think the second term is zero because spherical chell is symmetry.* The denominator isn’t spherically symmetric.

Comment: @Ghoster, I was foolish. I understand now. Thank you.